# Regex to replace a string

Tags: regex, search, vim, replace, vi

In VI I need to replace a pattern that looks like this:

seq- followed by exactly 24 chars (can be 0-9, a-z, A-Z only) followed by / followed by some number of (0-9, a-z, A-Z). So an example string would be:

seq-BzFk78qrJBkbnv1KkxppsfG4/92191_A_B

I want to replace the above string with a fixed string:

seq-ID/NUM_ID

How do I do this in Vi or Vim? I tried a few things like

```
  :%s/seq-[a-zA-Z0-9]{24}/[a-zA-Z0-9]{+}/seq-ID/NUM_ID
```

But it doesnt' work..

Comment: Cross Post: http://vi.stackexchange.com/q/9690/46

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to be careful with how you use quantifier and you must escape the `/`. Try this

```
:%s/^seq-[a-zA-Z0-9]\{24\}\/.*$/seq-ID\/NUM_ID/
```